# Is possible set static IP between 2 devices with nmcli

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I have a computer that has a wireless connection and has an ethernet. I need to communicate with a connected device through a local network created between my computer and this device (communication will be done via TCP/IP using socket).

For this communication, I need my computer to have the IP 192.168.0.57 (will be the host) on the ethernet. The other device expects to have the IP 192.168.0.201, so I need my computer to provide that ip at the other end.

Is it possible to configure it using NetworkManager (nmcli)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish doing this?  You can just assign each adapter the IP addresses you have listed so why are you using nmcli?

Comment: Is there a router between your computer and the device? or both connected each other directly?

Comment: @DubStep I can't configure the other device. It is configured to receive the ip 192.168.0.201. I need to create this "subnet" between it and my pc.

Comment: @3735943886 Both are connected to each other. I think I'll have to use dnsmasq for that...

Comment: @JoeyFran Likely. If the device is connected to your computer directly, and the device requests IP to your computer, then you have to set up DHCP server on your computer with dnsmasq or dhcpd. It cannot be done solely with nmcli.

Comment: Thank you @3735943886.